# Java-MongoDB Casting an array to a MongoCollection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I wonder if it is possible to re-search a document of a collection within an array, in MongoDB. Like this example:

**JSON of Mongo**

```
{
value1 : "aaa",
arrayvalue : [{
    value2 : "aaaaa",
    value3 : 1
    },{
    value2 : "aaaa",
    value3 : 2
    }]
}
{
value1 : "aaa",
arrayvalue : [{
    value2 : "bbbb",
    value3 : 3
    },{
    value2 : "bbbbb",
    value3 : 4
    }]
}
```

**Java code**

```
public static String getValue3(){
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test2");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("test1");
    if(collection == null)
        return "";
    Document doc = collection.find(and(eq("value1", "aaa"), eq("arrayvalue.value2", "aaaa"))).first();
    if(doc != null){
        MongoCollection<Document> arrayv = (MongoCollection<Document>) doc.get("arrayvalue");
        Document newdoc = arrayv.find(eq("value2", "aaaa")).first();
        return newdoc.get("value3").toString();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Obviously this didn't work (the right result would be "2"). Can anyone help me to get this value3 number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your query to use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection.

The below code `collection.find(filter)` with `projection(elemMatch(filter))`  returns the `arrayvalue` with single matching element for query and projection filter.

`doc.get("arrayvalue", List.class)` to read the `arrayvalue` which will be `[{value2 : "aaaa", value3 : 2}]`

`arrayValue.get(0).get("value3")` to read the `value3`.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.elemMatch;

 public static String getValue3(){
      MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
      MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test2");
      MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("test1");
      if(collection == null)
        return "";
      Document doc = collection.find(eq("value1", "aaa")).projection(elemMatch("arrayvalue", eq("value2", "aaaa"))).first();
      if(doc != null) {
        List<Document> arrayValue = doc.get("arrayvalue", List.class);
        return arrayValue.get(0).get("value3").toString();
      }
      return "";
 }
```